# Adding a static entry in the DNS server that is not in a zone

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I need to create a static entry in my dns server (windows2008) so that entries for any particular domain (e.g. yahoo.com) resolves to a specific IP address. It seems that my ISP is having problems with their domain information and we keep getting the incorrect information from their DNS servers.

Question: How do I add this entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a static entry you could create a conditional forward for yahoo.com to a public DNS server such as google's (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4). This would avoid problems if you have other forwarders setup for your DNS needs.

The conditional forward will only forward requests for yahoo.com to the server specified, rather than forwarding all unresolved requests.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use conditional forwarders in this case. My assumption is that the ISP DNS is problematic so the OP will wind up needing to set up conditional forwarders for multiple domains, which will quickly become cumbersome. I would eliminate the ISP DNS from the picture completely by setting up 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as forwarders instead of the ISP DNS, or better yet, use root hints instead of forwarders (which is what I prefer to do).

Comment: True, I was going off the assumption that the problem was only with a particular domain.  However, you are correct it would be more cumbersome to manage the conditional forwards if the ISP DNS is have issues as a whole.

Comment: We've had problems with "one particular domain" escalate to the point where I sent our ISP a nasty note and changed my DNS server to use root hints instead of forwarders.  From my admittedly limited sample set, if an ISP's DNS is crap for one zone it's probably crap for N (|N>1), and you'll have trouble when you least expect or need it...

Comment: the problem is with a particular domain (so far). If it does become problematic, then I might switch to another dns provider altogether.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution would be to:

1. Use different forwarders, such as 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

OR

2. Use root hints instead of forwarders

Comment: +1 for root hints - Eliminates a lot of potential problems by shortening the lookup path.

Comment: @vortaq7: Can you explain further, about the shortened lookup paths?